# Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker

Tags: firebase, push-notification

This is my code based on tutorial from firebase for web push notification:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: ".....................",
      authDomain: "push-test-8e36f.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "................",
      projectId: "................",
      storageBucket: "..................",
      messagingSenderId: "SOME SENDER ID"
    };
    let a = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    console.log(a);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    async function askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications(siteName) {
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      await messaging.requestPermission();
      const token = await messaging.getToken();

      console.log('user token: ' + token);

    }
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (result) {
      if (result === 'granted') {
        askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications('somesite');
        return;
      } else {
        console.log('The permission request was dismissed.');
        return;
      }
    });
  </script>
```

However, I always face with the problem involve in service worker, in every tutorial dont mention about that.

Any recommendations to fix this issue?